# UIViewController's nibName is nill on iPad but not nill on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have a view controller `LoginViewController` which including a xib file `LoginViewController.xib`. I log the controller's nibName in code. When I run the project on iPhone simulator, the nibName is not nil and it is the correct nib name and everything works. But when I run the project on iPad, the nibName is nil.

The code to init LoginViewController are. The controller and nib file are located in framework.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"FavorLibraryResources" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
LoginViewController *controller = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([LoginViewController class]) bundle:bundle];
```

I found the problem, I opened the `FavorLibraryResources.bundle` and there is a `LoginViewController~iphone.xib` file in it. But the xib name is `LoginViewController.xib`. It seems xcode add `~iphone` to the filename automatically. But it won't generate `~ipad` version of xib. So this xib is not loading on iPad.

Comment: Show your nib file name and your line where you init this nib.

Comment: are you using different XIB for both?

Comment: @jay I am use the same xib for iPad and iPhone.

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: Pls see the updated code.

Comment: Are you sure the xib is being copied correctly? Got to `Targets > Build Phases > Copy Resources` and ensure the xib is listed there. It could be that you built to your iPhone once before accidentally deleting the xib so the iPhone is working with stale data

Comment: @Paul.s Yes. I am pretty sure I have copied the xib file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code, and also verify Nib names:

```
NSString * nibName = @"LoginViewController";

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
   nibName = @"LoginViewController_iPad";

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"FavorLibraryResources" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
LoginViewController *controller = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:bundle];
```

Comment: But there is no LoginViewController_iPad file. Do I have to create two xibs?

Comment: yes if you want different layout for iPhone and iPad, if there is no difference, then you can use only "LoginViewController" as nib name.

Comment: I don't want different layout for iPhone and iPad. I am using only `LoginViewController` as nib name. But the problem is the nib file is not loaded on iPad.

Comment: @yong ho lets have a private chat,,

Comment: Make sure your application is universal, and then use same nib name for iphone. Then share your results with me.

Comment: The application is universal, and the nib name is the same. When I ask the question at the first time, it is what it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100211/discussion-between-yong-ho-and-aamir).